# Parallel python and subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, parallel-python

I'm trying to make a cluster using Parallel Python (pp) module.
I have set up the cluster. Nodes are available:

```
./ppserver.py -p 35000 -i 127.0.0.1 -s "mysecret"
```

master is also configured and jobs are submitted:

```
ppservers=("node-1:35000", "node-2:35000")
job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers, secret="mysecret")

f1 = job_server.submit(SomeFunction, argus1), modules=('subprocess',))
f2 = job_server.submit(SomeFunction, argus2), modules=('subprocess',))

a = f2()
b = f1()
```

SomeFunction:

```
def SomeFunction(argus):
  proc = subprocess.check_output(['python',
                    '~/path/to/python_script.py',
                    '--argu1', argus[0],
                    '--argu2', argus[1],
    ])
  return proc
```

`python_script.py` talks to youtube api and writes data into mysql database.

on execution i'm getting this error:

```
An error has occured during the function execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ppworker.py", line 90, in run
    __result = __f(*__args)
  File "<string>", line 16, in SomeFunction
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python', '~/path/to/python_script.py', '--argu1', 'argu1', '--argu2', 'argu2']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

`python_script.py` is fully debuged, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your path contains a `~`, which isn't expanded by default.

2 ways to fix that:

- add `shell=True` argument to run through a shell (not recommended)
- best way: use `os.path.expanduser`

like this:

```
proc = subprocess.check_output(['python',
                    os.path.expanduser('~/path/to/python_script.py'),
                    '--argu1', 'argu1',
                    '--argu2', 'argu2',
```